# Blocking websites for a user account

Tags: security, web-browsing

I want to block certain websites for a user account - but at the same time still allow all the other accounts on the computer to access the sites - whats the best way to do this ?

I was looking at Firefox add on but these are pretty easy to get around - ie. just change the browser, is there a user account wide way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need the Parental Controls preference pane in System Preferences. About six seconds into this video there's a screenshot suggesting you can limit access to certain websites: http://support.apple.com/kb/VI28

Comment: Actually this looks really useful for limiting computer use, maybe I should enable them for myself.